# AngularJs setting a default value to select

Tags: angularjs, html-select

Hi all i have the following code:

```
 <select class="form-control" 
    ng-init="mod = getPet.name" 
    ng-model="mod"  
    ng-options="pet.value as pet.name for pet in pets" >
 </select>
```

getPet function:

```
$scope.getPet = CommonSrv.getPetById(2);
```

getPetById searches an array for the pet with the id

my understanding of this is that mod is the current value of the select so whatever mod is will be reflected in the default value, however I am getting a blank select box instead of a populated default pet name.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you could do  it in your controller directly. $scope.mod=$scope.getPet().name

Comment: what is getPet function?

Comment: I have tried this but it does not change the result, i still get a blank area in the options. interestingly when i do <pre>{{mod}}</pre> i see the expected string

Comment: @dfsq i will add the code one moment.

Answer (score 0):

The value your select is putting in your model is the pet.value not the pet.name. So in order to init the default value you should put the getpet.value

Comment: thankyou, well that was staring me right in the face -_-